# Windows 10 Lan - How to share a folder to only a specific computer

Tags: windows-10, lan

I have a lan network with a bunch of Windows 10 computers (PRO version 2004).
Each computer have a specific computer name and they all belong to the same workgroup.

One of the computers is our "storage computer" which contains multiple folders that are shared in the network (any computer can access to those folders).

I would like to share some of those folders only with one computer of the network. Is it possible at all? please could you advise me on how to achieve it?

Please note that I would like to avoid creating Microsoft accounts or windows login accounts with password (if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user up on the Storage Computer.

Then you can share the folder to that user. You can do this for any number of users.  This is done from the sharing computer, not the remote computer

You may need to use passwords (nothing wrong with that) but you do not need to use Microsoft Accounts.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. That is what I thought, however I can't seem to add a user from a different computer. In the Permissions window, I click on Add, then if I type the user from the computer I want to share, Windows don't recognize it, and if I click on Locations only the location of the computer I am on appears. Is there any step that I am missing?

Comment: You need to add it from the Sharing computer. That works - I use that method. Other computers will not be able to add themselves - that is normal security. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Only when computers are inside a domain can you go cross computer. With workgroups, you are resorted to creating the users on the storage computer. If the username and password is the same as on another computer, that user will not get a login prompt and it will work seamlessly until their password on their computer changes, then they get a login prompt.

Comment: "With workgroups, you are resorted to creating the users on the storage computer."  Yes and as I posted above. Password does not need to be the same if passwords are used (highly recommended).

Comment: Thanks a lot John and LPChip, I've managed to make it work. It was a bit wacky, but having an user in both computers with the exact same name did the trick. I was expecting the sharing to be a bit more clever and detect users or computers within the same workgroup. Anyway, it is working! thanks a lot!!

Comment: Same names work. Different names with passwords also works - that is how I do it here on my own LAN network.